# Scrapy: only parse from pages with meta noindex

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am trying to crawl a website and parse only from pages with meta noindex.
What is happening is that the crawler crawls the first level, but finishes with the first page.  It does not seem to follow the links.
The following is my code:

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from wallspider.items import Website


class mydomainSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "0resultsTest"
    allowed_domains = ["www.mydomain.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mydomain.com/cp/3944"]

    rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),deny=()), callback="parse_items", follow= True,),
    )

    def _response_downloaded(self, response):
        sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        if sel.xpath('//meta[@content="noindex"]'):
            return super(mydomainSpider, self).parse_items(response)
        return

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//html')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = Website()
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
            item['title'] = site.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract()
            item['robots'] = site.select('//meta[@name="robots"]/@content').extract()
            items.append(item)

        yield items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the original `_response_downloaded` calls `_parse_response` function that besides calling `callback` function also follow links, from scrapy code:

```
def _parse_response(self, response, callback, cb_kwargs, follow=True):
    if callback:
        cb_res = callback(response, **cb_kwargs) or ()
        cb_res = self.process_results(response, cb_res)
        for requests_or_item in iterate_spider_output(cb_res):
            yield requests_or_item

    if follow and self._follow_links:
        for request_or_item in self._requests_to_follow(response):
            yield request_or_item
```

you can add that follow link part though I believe it's not the best way to go (leading `_` may imply just that), why not just check for `meta` in the beginning of your `parse_items` function? and if you don't want to repeat this test maybe even write a python decorator.

Comment: Checking for the meta in the beginning of my parse_items does seem like the easiest route.  I'll try it out, thanks again Guy!

Comment: My code below doesn't seem parse any urls, am I correctly checking the metas before parsing?

Comment: nop, your code looks good, try to add prints / logs for debugging, for example `print response.url` right at the beginning of `parse_items` function

Comment: Found the error - `ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem or None, got 'list' in <GET http://www.mydomain.com/browse/electronics/digital-cameras/3944_3959/`
Looks like  i should return items instead of yield.

Comment: either yield item by item or accumulate them in a list ans return it, but cant yield a list, yielding item y item is better IMO

Answer (score 0):

I believe checking for the meta at the beginning of my parse_items as @Guy Gavriely suggested will be my best option.  I will test out the following code below to see.

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from wallspider.items import Website


class mydomainSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "0resultsTest"
    allowed_domains = ["www.mydomain.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mydomain.com/cp/3944"]

    rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),deny=()), callback="parse_items", follow= True,),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//html')
        items = []

        if hxs.xpath('//meta[@content="noindex"]'):
            for site in sites:
                item = Website()
                item['url'] = response.url
                item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
                item['title'] = site.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract()
                item['robots'] = site.select('//meta[@name="robots"]/@content').extract()
                items.append(item)

            yield items
```

Working code update, I needed to return items instead of yield:

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from wallspider.items import Website


class mydomainSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "0resultsTest"
    allowed_domains = ["www.mydomain.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mydomain.com/cp/3944"]

    rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),deny=()), callback="parse_items", follow= True,),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//html')
        items = []

        if hxs.xpath('//meta[@content="noindex"]'):
            for site in sites:
                item = Website()
                item['url'] = response.url
                item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
                item['title'] = site.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract()
                item['robots'] = site.select('//meta[@name="robots"]/@content').extract()
                items.append(item)

            return items
```